# How does one use SPICE to compute the Greenwich sidereal time as an angle?

Tags: spice

I'm looking at the BMW book<sup>†</sup> and see that equation 7.5-7 gives $\alpha_0 = \theta = \theta_g + \lambda_E$ as the equation for right ascension (for some launch site at east longitude $\lambda_E$). $\theta_g$ is Greenwich sidereal time at launch, presumably as an angle.

I know that SPICE contains a routine `et2lst` which can be used with longitude 0 to get Greenwich sidereal time in h/m/s, but how can I use SPICE to calculate GST in radians instead?

It looks like there's [an equation for it](http://www.astro.umd.edu/~jph/GST_eqn.pdf), but if SPICE has already implemented this, I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

---

<sup>†</sup>Fundamentals of Astrodynamics, Roger R. Bate,  Donald D. Mueller, Jerry E. White

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: If the planet of interest is the Earth, I strongly suggest you consider using the [Standards of Fundamental Astronomy](http://www.iausofa.org) library rather than SPICE.

That said, hour angle is a measure of angle rather than time. To convert the sexagesimal hour angle to a decimal hour angle, use $h{:}m{:}s \to h+(m + s/60)/60$. This decimal hour angle can readily be converted to degrees by multiplying by 15 (there are 360 degrees or 24 hours in one revolution), or to radians by multiplying by $\pi/12$.

Comment: I figured it would be that simple. Thank you, Dave. Good to hear from you; I hope you're well.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a simple way to find the equinox in SPICE? I find myself wanting to check the results, and finding right ascension of Greenwich at the equinox seems to be the best spot-check.